# Changing the order of integration - verify strange limits of integration

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

I have been trapped by the following, most probably very simple situation: I have the integral

$$I = \int_0^{\infty} f(x) \int_{-\infty}^{ax +b}h(y) dy dx,\;\;\; a>0, b\in\mathbb R$$

and assume any regularity condition required.

Now, I *need* to change the order of integration. One moment it appears that I should write

$$I = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} h(y) \int_{\max\{(y-b)/a,\,0\}}^{\infty}f(x) dxdy $$

but the next  moment the picture changes to

$$I = \int_{b}^{\infty} h(y) \int_{(y-b)/a}^{\infty}f(x) dxdy $$

The following moment, both make no sense to me. And the cycle repeats. Too tired, obviously. Any help or hints?

Comment: I would take a look at this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/183003/222527).  I think it would probably get you what you need...

Comment: For $b\ge 0$, we have

$$\begin{align}
I&=\int_0^\infty f(x)\int_{-\infty}^{ax+b}h(y)\,dy\,dx\\\\
&=\int_0^\infty f(x) \int_{-\infty}^{b}h(y)\,dy\,dx+\int_0^\infty f(x)\int_{b}^{ax+b}h(y)\,dy\,dx\\\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^b h(y) \int_0^\infty f(x) \,dx\,dy+\int_b^\infty h(y) \int_{(y-b)/a}^\infty f(x)\,dx\,dy
\end{align}$$

Comment: @MarkViola Thanks, this clears things.

Comment: @MarkViola That looks worth making an answer of.

Comment: @MarkViola It appears the above is valid irrespective of the sign of $b$.

Comment: @AlecosPapadopoulos Well, I was only posting a comment to possibly help the OP.

Comment: @MarkViola That's me, and you certainly did!

Comment: @AlecosPapadopoulos Pleased to hear!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you draw the region of integration, 
there is a line $y = ax+b$ that crosses the $y$-axis,
and the region of integration is everything under this line and to the right
of the $y$-axis.
For the integral
$\iint dy\,dx$ it seems relatively straightforward
to get the limits of the inner integral:
at each value $x$ you take the vertical line through $(x,0)$
and integrate on the part of that vertical line that is below $y=ax+b.$

But if you change the order of integration to $\iint dx\,dy,$
now for each $y$ you integrate on some part of a horizontal line
through $(0,y)$
on the right side of the $y$ axis but also under the line $y=ax+b.$
The tricky thing is, when $a>0$ the points underneath $y=ax+b$
are to the right of $y=ax+b,$
so the portion of each horizontal line that you integrate over is whatever
is both to the right of the $y$-axis and also to the right of $y=ax+b.$
That is, in the region of integration you have two conditions that are
always simultaneously true: $x \geq 0$ and $x \geq (y-b)/a.$
You can write this as $x \geq \max\{(y-b)/a, 0\}.$
But any value of $y$ can be found in the region of integration
(as long as you pair it with a large enough $x$), so
\begin{align}
I &= \int_0^\infty f(x) \int_{-\infty}^{ax +b} h(y)\, dy\, dx \\[.8ex]
&= \int_{-\infty}^\infty h(y) \int_{\max\{(y-b)/a,0\}}^\infty f(x)\,dx\,dy
\\[.8ex]
&= \int_{-\infty}^b h(y) \int_0^\infty f(x)\, dx\,dy
    + \int_{b}^{\infty} h(y) \int_{(y-b)/a}^{\infty}f(x) \,dx\,dy.
\end{align}

So your integral
$\int_{b}^{\infty} h(y) \int_{(y-b)/a}^{\infty}f(x) \,dx\,dy$
is not exactly *wrong,* but it only tells you about the part of the region of integration above the line $y=b,$
and you also have to integrate below that line.

Comment: Thanks. It seems your second line is the first thought I had, with the max operator.

Comment: The max operator was correct; it just makes for a possibly awkward integration. The third line merely considers separately the two cases of $\max\{(y-b)/a,0\}$: one for $y < b$ (the value comes out to $0$) and one for $y \geq b$ (the value comes out to $(y-b)/a$).